# Why does this custom React hook using useContext useEffect and setInterval fail in test

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test a custom React hook.

I don't understand why new context is not being used when callback function inside setInterval runs.

The problem can't be with @testing-library/react as it rerenders with new context just fine. Most likely there is something going on between useContext, useEffect and setInterval, but I have no clue what.

Custom React hook 'useCustomContext.ts':

```js
import { useContext, useEffect, useRef, createContext } from 'react';

export const CustomContext = createContext('');

export const useValueFromContext = function() {
  const context = useContext(CustomContext);
  const ref = useRef('');

  function getContext() {
    return context;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = getContext();
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      ref.current = getContext();
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return ref.current;
};

export default useValueFromContext;
```

Failing test 'useCustomContext.test.tsx':

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useValueFromContext, CustomContext } from './useCustomContext';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

test('Should return value from most recently provided context', async () => {
  const Component = () => {
    const value = useValueFromContext();
    return <span data-testid="context">{value}</span>;
  };

  const { getByTestId, rerender } = render(
    <CustomContext.Provider value="a">
      <Component />
    </CustomContext.Provider>,
  );

  rerender(
    <CustomContext.Provider value="b">
      <Component />
    </CustomContext.Provider>,
  );

  await new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      rerender(
        <CustomContext.Provider value="b">
          <Component />
        </CustomContext.Provider>,
      );
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  });

  expect(getByTestId('context').textContent).toBe('b');
});
```

Output:

```
Should return value from most recently provided context

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "b"
    Received: "a"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I had to add context to the useEffect dependencies like so:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = getContext();
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      ref.current = getContext();
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [context]);
```